# m3u8 file on computer opened with notepad any suggestions

Tags: m3u8

First of all I am not an IT professional. I found file on my laptop which has .m3u8 extension. I downloaded VLC media player but that file does not show anything. It has following code. What is it?
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2129600,RESOLUTION=1820x1024,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2"
0/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1029600,RESOLUTION=1138x640,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
1/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=589600,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2"
2/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=334400,RESOLUTION=426x240,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
3/manifest.m3u8

I downloaded VLC media player. It did not play anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a HLS multivariant playlist, as defined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-12.

Each EXT-X-STREAM-INF points a variant of the same media (audio and video) at different qualities.

To play it, you'd need the file you have, the variant playlists and the media referenced within the variant playlists.